# Helper Class not Accessible from View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, helper, session-cookies

I defined a helper class as below

```
module SessionsHelper

  def current_user 
        @current_user= User.find_by_fbid(session[:fbid])
  end


  def sign_in(user)
        session[:fbid] = user.fbid
        @current_user = user

  end


  def signed_in?
       !current_user.nil?
  end


  end
```

I included the Helper Class in my Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper


end
```

The sign in method gets called from Session Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController


  def create

  user = User.find_or_create_by_fbid(params[:user][:fbid]) 
  user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  sign_in(user)
  redirect_to user_path(user)

  end

end
```

However I am not able to access 'current_user' variable from users#show view.

```
 <% if signed_in? %>
<p>
  <b>Current User:</b>
  <%= current_user.name %>
</p>


<% end %>
```

It says : undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Can anyone please advise ?
The method current_user does  not get called at all from index.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Putting `include SessionsHelper` in your controller includes those module methods in the controller, so they are accessible in your controller methods. You want the helper methods available in your views, so you need to use `helper SessionsHelper` in your application controller.

That being said, I do agree with Jits that the methods you have in SessionsHelper really do belong in the controller instead of in a helper.

Comment: Thanks. Including helper SessionsHelper did solve the access issue.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should have methods like `current_user` defined in your `application_controller` and then make them available as helpers in the views. This way the controllers have access to them (and trust me, you will most likely need access to things like that). Example:

```rb
def current_user
  ..
end
helper :current_user
```

Comment: But I have included the Helper class in ApplicationController. Saw something similar in some tutorial. Hence went this way .

Comment: I just added the <% if signed_in? %> code snippet in the view. The signed_in? function gets called. But it fails to find the current user.

Comment: I believe that should be helper_method instead of helper

Answer (score 0):

What helped me:

- Define methods to use in the **controller** in **helper files**
- Define methods to use in the **view** in the relevant **model** file

#### Example

Suppose you had this in `user_helper.rb`

```rb
def something
 2 + 2
end
```

simply move that code into

`models/user.rb`

and it will be accessible in the view without any further effort.